# In Elastic Search, how do you bulk index a Json file multi-value documents all at once?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've already looked through ES documentation and read related questions, but none of them have worked for me thus far.

Basically I have a Json file with written with multiple documents in this format:

```
[ { 
    "account": "Sam420", 
    "language": null, 
    "watchers": 0, 
    "commits": 14, 
    "contributors": 2, 
    "stars": 0, 
    "rank": 16, 
}
{ 
    "account": "Kelly", 
    "language": null, 
    "watchers": 0, 
    "commits": 14, 
    "contributors": 2, 
    "stars": 0, 
    "rank": 16, 
} ]
```

I have tried post request using the bulk API to my local ES setup with this following the following body format:

```
 { "index": {} }
 { 
    "account": "Kelly", 
    "language": null, 
    "watchers": 0, 
    "commits": 14, 
    "contributors": 2, 
    "stars": 0, 
    "rank": 16, 
} 
{ "index": {} }
{ 
    "account": "Kelly", 
    "language": null, 
    "watchers": 0, 
    "commits": 14, 
    "contributors": 2, 
    "stars": 0, 
    "rank": 16, 
}
```

But, I'm getting a parser error. It does work when I rearrange data into one single row per data like this:

```
{ "index": { "_index": "folder" } }
{ "account": "Sam420", "language": null, ... }
{ "index": { "_index": "Canigan"} }
{ "account": "Kelly", "language": null, ... }
```

Here's the parser error:

```
{
    "error": {
    "root_cause": [
       {
          "type": "json_parse_exception",
          "reason": "Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): expected a      
                    valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true',     
                    'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@6bd0ddf7; line: 
                    1, column: 10]"
        }],
           "type": "json_parse_exception",
           "reason": "Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): expected a 
                     valid value (number, String, array, object 'true', 
                    'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@6bd0ddf7; line: 
                    1, column: 10]"
       },
       "status": 500
}
```

But, I'm pulling repo data with 100+ documents from Github API, and each value is arranged vertically. Without having to reformat it using script, what can I do to bulk index multiple documents in the Json format that's already given to me? If not, is there any other way besides bulk index I can use to index multiple documents at once?

Comment: can you paste your parse error and query..?

Comment: Added as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for version 5.5 makes this pretty clear:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

> Because this format uses literal \n's as delimiters, please be sure
>   that the JSON actions and sources are not pretty printed.

You *must* lay out the objects as single lines.

That being said, you don't really need a complicated script to reformat your objects.  You could use something like Notepad++ to replace ",\n" (comma then newline) with ", " (comma then space).  Then interleave your index/metadata lines like you're doing.

You might also need to watch out for the trailing comma at the end of your list of properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work because you have no information about the index and the index type.

```
{ "index": {"my_index", "my_index_type"} }
{ "account": "Sam420", "language": null, ... }
{ "index": {"my_index", "my_index_type"} }
{ "account": "Kelly", "language": null, ... }
```

Comment: I have also tried that as well. I've included headers with just index, index and type, and index, type, and ID combination. But, none of them worked. Like I said, the bulk request works when values are laid out horizontally. But, Github api doesn't lay it out in that manner. It's vertical.